# Create a table from two tables in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables(let's say A and B) in my PostgreSQL database and I want to create a third table from the columns of A and B.

Here are the columns of A and B

```
A:             B:

Load_ID        T_ID
M_ID           From
From           To
To             T_type
M_type         T_length
T_type         T_weight
T_length       #Trucks
T_weight       Price
#Trucks        T_rating
Loading_day    Loading_day
```

The third table(**C**) must have all the columns from both tables where From,To,T_type,T_length, T_weight, #Trucks and Loading_day matches each other. Also Loading day is a date column, I am not sure how to compare them.

I tried doing this(see pusedo-code):

```
select columns name from both tables 
from A,B
where  compare columns
```

Is there a better way of doing this ? like merge them on selected columns ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do join and compare like below-

```
select A.*, B.* from tableA A inner join tableB B
on A.From=B.To and to=T_type and T_type =T_length 
and others columns...
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Join (one of the flavors, depending on what you want). If you want to get a table C of only the entries in A and B where those columns match each other, you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM A a INNER JOIN B b ON a.From = b.from AND a.to = b.to AND ... ;
```